# C++ pointer/object error

Tags: c++, pointers, object, scope, sfml

I have this code, where I'm creating a SFML-Text object. But when I try to put this into a function I get an error. I have a programming background in Java, and this pointer-thing confuses me.

Is this a problem caused by incorrect use of pointers/reference, or because of object not surviving the scope? Or, is it something else?

```
void createDisplayText(sf::Text *text, string content, sf::Font font)
{
    text->setFont(font);
    text->setCharacterSize(24);
    text->setString("Money: 0");
}

//Main function
sf::Text energyText;
createDisplayText(&energyText, "Energy: ", font);
energyText.move(0, 30);


//Main loop
    window.draw(energyText);
```

I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0F58FE8C (sfml-graphics-d-2.dll) in SFML_testing.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000C.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of `createDisplayText`, ie. `font`, is the (or "a") problem. If you call `createDisplayText` with some font there, it gets copied, the copy is used within the function, and deleted again when the function ends.

But in the function, you call `text->setFont`, which takes a *reference*: It won´t copy the parameter again, but uses your first copy directly. And as said before, this first copy gets deleted soon after. While this is no problem for `text->setFont` (because it has ended too if `createDisplayText` ends), it stores the font somewhere in the Text class for later use. And then...

(See the docs for setFont too: "The font argument refers to a font
that must exist as long as the text uses it.")

One solution of many: Pass the font of `createDisplayText` per reference too (`sf::Font &font` instead of `sf::Font font`) and take care that the font in main (etc.) will survive until it´s not needed anymore (it´s hard to say how without knowing the main function).

PS: In Java, everything behaves like a pointer. The non-pointer stuff *should* be the real confusing part...

Answer (score 1):

It is almost impossible to find a bug in code above. The lucky guess is that your variable `energyText` goes out of the scope, when you are passing it to main loop.

Probably the best would be to run it with GDB and Valgrind.

Comment: Is there any further code I could provide, as to clarify?

Comment: @NaioaiStudios run it with GDB and Valgrind.